# Neo4j: Does 'NOT CONTAINS' exist in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Do you know if exists 'not contains' in Neo4j ?

For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///animal.csv' as a fieldterminator "|"
match (b:Animals{animal:a.type})
where not a.type contains 'x' or not a.type contains 'abc'
set b.type=a.type
```

Unfortunately in this way the code doesn't work.

Comment: no something similar at 'not like'

Comment: Why do you say that your query is not working ?

Comment: In this way even when I have the 'x' value the set is executed

Comment: case sensitivity? or parenthesis. I would also move the WHERE before the MATCH `WITH a WHERE ... `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that contains is *case sensitive*
I would also move the WHERE before the match, it's cheaper there

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///animal.csv' as a fieldterminator "|"
WITH a where (not (a.type contains 'x')) or (not (a.type contains 'abc'))
match (b:Animals{animal:a.type})
set b.type=a.type
```

Are you also sure you want an OR there and not an AND ?

Comment: Note that toLower(str) can be used to make it case-insensitive. https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-tolower